# Deriving the Nelson-Siegel model

Tags: integration, finance

The [Nelson-Siegel (1987)](http://web.math.ku.dk/%7E/rolf/teaching/NelsonSiegel.pdf) model states that the instantaneous forward rate at maturity, $r(m)$ is given as:
$$\beta_0 + \beta_1 e^{(-m/\tau)} + \beta_2\left(\frac{m}{\tau}e^{(-m/\tau)}\right) \tag{1}
$$
The yield to maturity, $R(m)$ is given by:
$$R(m) = \frac{1}{m}\int_0^mr(x)dx \tag{2}
$$

On solving $(2)$ I get the following as $R(m)$:
$$ R(m) = \beta_0 + \frac{(\beta_1+\beta_2)(1- e^{(-m/\tau)})}{\frac{m}{\tau}} - \beta_2\frac{e^{(-m/\tau)}}{\tau} \tag{3}
$$

However the correct equation for $R(m)$ is given in the paper as:
$$ R(m) = \beta_0 + \frac{(\beta_1+\beta_2)(1- e^{(-m/\tau)})}{\frac{m}{\tau}} - \beta_2e^{(-m/\tau)} \tag{4}
$$

I feel like I did the integration wrong but no matter what, I simply cannot get the $\tau$ to disappear in the last term of $(3)$. Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result in the paper is correct as written.  Since you have not provided the details of your computation, I cannot tell you why you have an extra $\tau$ in the denominator of the $\beta_2$ term.  If you would like to have such an explanation, you will need to furnish the intermediate calculations that resulted in $(3)$.

For the sake of simplicity, let us define

$$f(x) = \beta_0 + (\beta_1 + \beta_2 x)e^{-x}.$$  Then $f(m/\tau) = r(m)$.  We also observe that $$\frac{d}{dx}[xe^{-x}] = e^{-x} + x(-e^{-x}) = (1-x)e^{-x}.$$
This suggests writing
$$f(x) = \beta_0 + (\beta_1 + \beta_2)e^{-x} - \beta_2(1 - x)e^{-x},$$ so that
$$\int f(x) \, dx = \beta_0 x - (\beta_1 + \beta_2)e^{-x} - \beta_2 x e^{-x} + C.$$

Consequently, with the substitution $x = \tau u$,
$$\begin{align}
R(m) &= \frac{1}{m} \int_{x=0}^m r(x) \, dx \\
&= \frac{\tau}{m} \int_{u=0}^{m/\tau} r(\tau u) \, du \\
&= \frac{\tau}{m} \int_{u=0}^{m/\tau} f(u) \, du \\
&= \frac{\tau}{m} \left( \beta_0  \frac{m}{\tau} - (\beta_1 + \beta_2) (e^{-m/\tau} - 1) - \beta_2 \frac{m}{\tau} e^{-m/\tau}\right) \\
&= \beta_0 + \frac{(\beta_1 + \beta_2)(1-e^{-m/\tau})}{m/\tau} - \beta_2 e^{-m/\tau}
\end{align}$$
as claimed.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I forgot to change the limits of my integration in my attempts.